# create-react-app: how do i run npm start in debug mode?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-start

create-react-app keep getting stuck at starting development server when running npm start. Nothing shows up in the console, process just seems to run idle forever. Probably a memory issue but increasing js heap does not seem to clear the issue entirely, so would love to run npm start in debug mode, but how?

Comment: if you want to debug without debug config , you can use npm start. When you launch the browser and start using your website, press F12 and go to console tag to debug by hand.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no debug mode for NPM.

You can open the development mode in the browser and set the breaking points in the code with issues.

Another way is to use the [Profiler](https://react.dev/reference/react/Profiler)

```
function onRender(id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration, startTime, commitTime) {
console.log({id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration, startTime, commitTime})
}
<Profiler id="App" onRender={onRender}>
   <App />
</Profiler>
```